# Maven - getting different versions when using jar as a dependency -> confusing

Tags: maven, spring-boot

As part of my project, I build a Spring Boot starter.

When I check the dependencies used in my starter, I don't get any conflicts. Pom.xml is available [here](https://github.com/societe-generale/ci-droid-tasks-consumer/blob/cidroid-tasks-consumer_1.1.0/ci-droid-tasks-consumer-starter/pom.xml). For example, I do get `jackson-databind` 2.9.8 in my starter 1.1.0

[image: proper dependencies]

Now, when I use my starter in another project, for which the only declared dependency is above starter :

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.societegenerale.ci-droid.tasks-consumer</groupId>
        <artifactId>ci-droid-tasks-consumer-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(example available [here](https://github.com/vincent-fuchs/custom-ci-droid-tasks-consumer/blob/master/pom.xml))

I would expect to see the exact same dependencies.. Well, I don't. **In that case, jackson-databind 2.8.9 "wins", not 2.9.8**

[image]

This is causing issues at runtime. It's pretty annoying, as I can't really distribute the starter easily if I can't guarantee which dependencies are going to come up when it's used.

Which Maven rule is at work here ? I don't get it.. And how can I make sure the proper version comes in the starter I distribute, so I don't need to tell people to declare versions explicitely when they use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, I don't known if it's the recommended way of doing or not, but this works. in the custom project that uses the starter, use the parent pom as a BOM, and the starter as a dependency, mentioning the version each time :

https://github.com/vincent-fuchs/custom-ci-droid-tasks-consumer/blob/2d9f0aff57685be38f7e8c269701dc3c2dac6ef0/pom.xml#L13-L40

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <ci-droid-tasks-consumer.version>1.1.0</ci-droid-tasks-consumer.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.societegenerale.ci-droid.tasks-consumer</groupId>
        <artifactId>ci-droid-tasks-consumer-parent</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <version>${ci-droid-tasks-consumer.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.societegenerale.ci-droid.tasks-consumer</groupId>
        <artifactId>ci-droid-tasks-consumer-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${ci-droid-tasks-consumer.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

If I import it like that, then `jackson-databinder` comes as in the main project, ie 2.9.8.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely `<dependencyManagement>` going on, either in your POM or in the Parent POM. This sets the version to 2.9.8.

In the other case, Maven follows the "neareast dependency wins" strategy, which results in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: indeed there is : https://github.com/societe-generale/ci-droid-tasks-consumer/blob/cidroid-tasks-consumer_1.1.0/pom.xml#L205-L209 and it's fine.My question is more like "why this is not preserved when I use the jar that is built ?" how can the "nearest dependency wins" strategy apply when there's only one dependency ? I don't have dependencyManagement in the "child" custom project, just 1 dependency : https://github.com/vincent-fuchs/custom-ci-droid-tasks-consumer/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: I believe that dependencyManagement in dependencies is ignored, but I do not have a source for that (I searched for it, but was not successful).

Comment: So if my comment is correct, you might get different dependencies if your project is used as dependency than in the build.

Comment: yes, my point exactly ;-) so what's the recommended way to avoid this ? because I can't test manually  every time I make a change in my pom.xml. Today it's jackson-databind, tomorrow it will be something else. That's how Spring does for hundreds of dependencies (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) and they have tons of starters that people use as dependencies. Surely they have a way to ensure it behaves the same whether their code is used directly or as a dependency

Comment: I would say: If something is a library, i.e. is meant to be a dependency, then avoid dependencyManagement. Do the dependencyManagement on the level of the actual application that you built, e.g. by using a BOM.